# Java: Transform coordinates from one system into another when 2 coordinate pairs are known

Tags: java, android, math

I am currently making an app for android where the user can touch a specific place on a map and gets information about that place. The map is a top-down view of a video game map, but that does not matter here. Basically, I know the video-game coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners and I need to know the video-game coordinate of the place the user touched.

If the user touches for example the point (500,500) on the displayed map, I want the coordinate of the video-game map at this position.

The problem here is that the API I use for the map gives the touched coordinate in a coordinate system starting from the top-left corner with (0,0) and increasing numbers to the bottom-right corner. The video game uses a more normal coordinate system with increasing numbers to the top (y) and right (x) and decreasing numbers to the bottom (y) and the left (x).

Do you know any way how I could transform the coordinates from the maps API into the video game coordinates?

[image]

Comment: While this question is code related (even though you showed no code), you might get a cleaner answer on [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on your example :

I assume that you used the notation (y,x) in your explanation and I'll use the same in this answer.(I believe you should use (x,y))

The top left VGC(video game coordinate) is (2403,1212) and the bottom right VGC is (-13,3084). So in the current situation there are 2403-(-13)=2416 possible y and 3084-1212 = 1872 possible x coordinates in VGC.

For Android coordinate system there are 1000 possible x and 1000 possible y coordinates.

If we try to map those : 2416/1000=2.416 and 1872/1000=1.872. So if Android y coordinate change by 1, VGC y coordinate will change by 2.416.

Let's say user touched (100,150) in android coordinates. Which means 100y and 150x far from upper left corner. Then you convert those into VGC changes, (100*2.416,150*1.872) roughly equals (241,281).

Now if the top left coordinate is (2403,1212), the touchdown in VGC coordinates would be (2403-241,1212+281).

Make top left and bottom right VGC variables in code and make calculations with same logic.